# What is the monotonicity of the sequence $a_{n+1} = -a_{n}^{2}+8a_n-10$ given that $a_1=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find the  monotonicity of the sequence $a_{n+1} = -a_n^{2}+8a_n-10$ where $a_1=0$

---

Taking the first terms we notice that $a_1 = 0, a_2 = -10, a_3 = - 190$.

Therefore, I made the hypothesis that the sequence is strictly decreasing and proved it by deduction.

1. For $n=1: a_1  > a_2 \iff 0 > -10$
2. For $n=k$ let $a_k > a_{k+1}$
3. For $n=k+1:$ An algebraic mess occurs...

---

Another approach is to prove that $a_n - a_{n+1} > 0 \iff$

$$a_{n} - a_n^{2}-8a_n+10 = ...$$ but that's a dead end.

---

Any other ideas on how to study the monotonicity of this sequence? There must be an easier way.

Comment: Is the left side of your equation $a_{n+1}$ instead of $a_n$?

Comment: What is $a$? Is it really $a^2n$ or you meant something like $a_n^2$ or $a_n^2n$?

Comment: Yes , I edited, thanks @ECL

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited, thanks

Comment: @Somos but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_n ≤ 0$, then $a_{n+1} - a_n = a_n(7 - a_n) - 10 < 0$, and so also $a_{n+1} < a_n ≤ 0$.

Comment: In short, you need to have “$a_n < a_{n-1}$ and $a_n < 0$” as induction invariant as for $n ∈ ℕ$, $$a_n < 0 \implies a_{n+1} < a_n \implies a_{n+1} < 0 \implies …$$

Comment: Good approach but it is not given that $a_n < 0$

Comment: @Veriun $a_2 < 0$. But apart from that, this also works for ‘$a_n ≤ 0$” (as edited) and $a_1 = 0$.

Comment: $a_1 < 0$ doesn't imply that $a_n <0$, right?

Comment: @Veriun Regard my first comment and ponder.

Comment: Basically we need two inductions, one to prove $a_n <0$ and then another one to prove that $a_{n+1} < a_n$. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Veriun We formally don’t need two inductions, though. Just take “$a_n < a_{n-1}$ and $a_n < 0$” as induction invariant. That’s one single statement (as a conjunction of two statements maybe, but still a single statement). You can of course prove $a_n < 0$ for all $n ∈ ℕ$ separately by induction first, but that’s really not needed. Proving statements by induction is all about finding the right induction invariant. You will encounter instances where you cannot prove by induction the actual statement you want to prove, but only a *stronger* version of it.

Answer (score 2):

Write $a_{n+1} = -a_{n}^{2}+8a_n-10$ as $a_{n+1} = -(a_{n}-4)^{2}+6$

That shows for $a_n \le 0$, $a_{n+1} \lt a_{n}$.

Comment: Math Lover, I guess there's a spurious sign in your $<$-relation in the end. In the current form, it does not imply monotonicity.
May I ask you to edit & amend ?

Comment: I just saw this comment and fixed it. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

You got $$a_{n} - (-a_n^{2}+8a_n-10) = a_n^2-7a_n+10 = (a_n-5)(a_n-2)$$

Since $a_n\leq 0$ this product is negative, so the sequance is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

What you consider to be a dead end is viable to show
$$a_{n+1} - a_n \:=\: -\,(a_n^2 -7a_n +10) \:=\: (a_n-2)(5-a_n) \;
\begin{cases}\geqslant 0 & \text{if }\:2\leqslant a_n\leqslant 5 \\
< 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$
the desired monotonicity, as in Aqua's answer.
When the iteration starts with $a_1=0$, then always the second line in the case distinction applies, hence the sequence $\,a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\,$ is strictly decreasing.

---

Another idea how to study the monotonicity properties, not necessarily an easier way, yields more quantitative insight via a closed-form expression for $\,a_n\,$ from which the monotonicity is deduced.

Similar to the answer by Math Lover one has
$$4-a_{n+1} \:=\: (4-a_n)^2 -2\,,$$
thus the linear term on recursion's RHS drops out. Let $\,b_n =4-a_n$,
and go for the ansatz
$$b_n \:=\: \beta^{2^{n-1}} + \big(\beta^{-1}\big)^{2^{n-1}} \\[1.5ex]
\implies b_n^2 \:=\: \beta^{2^n} +2 +\big(\beta^{-1}\big)^{2^n} \:=\: b_{n+1}+2$$
so that the recursion is satisfied.
$\beta\,$ is determined by the start value. From $\,4=b_1=\beta+\beta^{-1}$ we have that $\,\beta=2\pm\sqrt3\iff\beta^{-1}=2\mp\sqrt3$, hence
$$b_n \:=\: \big(2+\sqrt3\big)^{2^{n-1}} + \big(2-\sqrt3\big)^{2^{n-1}}$$
which is super-exponentially (and also strictly) growing.

Notice that it is a particular property of the given quadratic recursion that the iterates can be written in closed-form. In general this is unavailable.